# Execute jQuery script if value is 1 inside a php echo in Joomla

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

I like to execute a jQuery Script if "Yes" is selected in the radio button. I am getting confused of how to implement the addScriptDeclaration from Joomla inside an echo, also I'm not sure if the call `if (count($displayonload) == '1'){` is the right way to get the value from the checkbox.

Explaining the xml code: The radio button in the backend of Joomla with value 0 if no and value 1 if yes is selected.

```
<field name="displayonload"
       type="radio" default="0" 
       label="Display Modal on load" 
       description="">
       class="btn-group btn-group-yesno">
       <option value="1">JYES</option>
</field>
```

The value 1 or 2 is stored like this:

```
 $displayonload  = $params->get('$displayonload');
```

The php code to echo the js script (jQuery):

```
if (count($displayonload) == '1'){
    echo '
      $document = JFactory::getDocument();
      $document->addScriptDeclaration('

      jQuery(window).load(function(){
      jQuery("#myModal").modal("show");
    });                
');'; 
}
```

Sorry if my code is a mess but I'm just starting with Joomla and PHP development.

Comment: you don't need javascript to open a modal you can just do a if on the class of the modal

Comment: any hint for this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, may this will help someone.

```
if ($params->get('displayonload', '0') == '1') {
      $document = JFactory::getDocument();
    $js = 'jQuery(window).load(function(){

      jQuery("#myModal").modal("show");
    });';
      $document->addScriptDeclaration($js); 
}
```